# I am trying to get the model number from an android tv programatically

Tags: android, android-tv, television

I've tried several ways to get the model number out of a Sony Android TV like  `Build.model` and `Build.name` but it returns me something like the name of the Tv (i.e Bravia 2015)
What I need is the full model number of that particular tv (i.e KDL-50W800C)
Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

Build.FINGERPRINT will probably have what you are looking for and then some. Snippet below from [android/os/Build.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java):

```
/** A string that uniquely identifies this build.  Do not attempt to parse this value. */
public static final String FINGERPRINT = deriveFingerprint();

/**
 * Some devices split the fingerprint components between multiple
 * partitions, so we might derive the fingerprint at runtime.
 */
private static String deriveFingerprint() {
    String finger = SystemProperties.get("ro.build.fingerprint");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finger)) {
        finger = getString("ro.product.brand") + '/' +
                getString("ro.product.name") + '/' +
                getString("ro.product.device") + ':' +
                getString("ro.build.version.release") + '/' +
                getString("ro.build.id") + '/' +
                getString("ro.build.version.incremental") + ':' +
                getString("ro.build.type") + '/' +
                getString("ro.build.tags");
    }
    return finger;
}
```

**Long Answer:**

It should be in the readable system properties (most likely one of those above). However its worth noting its not guaranteed to be populated consistently on all devices/builds.

Here are a few ways to pull the data:

1. Programmatically via [android/os/Build.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java) - for a finite set of properties, as you did above
2. Programmatically via [java.lang.System.getProperty](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) - using [getProperties(optional string)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperties())
3. Outside of runtime just to debug/see whats up via [terminal$ adb shell getprop](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#shellcommands) - which'll print em all out

Here are some examples (1st emulator, 2nd custom-built TV STB)

```
[ro.build.fingerprint]: [generic_x86/sdk_google_atv_x86/generic_x86:5.1.1/LMY48X/2916408:userdebug/test-keys]
[ro.build.product]: [generic_x86]
[ro.build.id]: [LMY48X]
[ro.hardware]: [ranchu]
[ro.product.brand]: [generic_x86]
[ro.product.device]: [generic_x86]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [unknown]
[ro.product.model]: [sdk_google_atv_x86]
[ro.product.name]: [sdk_google_atv_x86]

[ro.build.fingerprint]: [Android/p202/p202:5.1.1/LMY44V/20170215:userdebug/release-keys]
[ro.build.product]: [p202]
[ro.build.id]: [LMY44V]
[ro.hardware]: [amlogic]
[ro.product.brand]: [Alta]
[ro.product.device]: [p202]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [AltaDigital]
[ro.product.model]: [H4401]
[ro.product.name]: [p202]
[ro.stb.chip]: [AMLOGICS905]
```

I'm not sure if/where all of the android os system properties can be found, and if somebody knows please add, but here are links for some of the system properties:

[Adding A New Device](https://source.android.com/source/add-device#prod-def), 
[DeviceSelectionOptions](https://source.android.com/reference/tradefed/com/android/tradefed/device/DeviceSelectionOptions.html#DEVICE_PRODUCT_PROPERTY)

Comment: Most of the same properties can be found in `/system/build.prop`